# When I use clangd in vscode, it always says clang language server client: couldn't create connection to server

Tags: visual-studio-code, clang++, clangd

[image][image]

I don't know if it's because she didn't connect to the server. She didn't have a code prompt,and didn't show underline and others, I want to fix it, exerting the effect she should have. There are two pictures，one is the problem.

The other picture is the part of my settings.json about clangd.

Comment: now，it`s ok，maybe clangd.params has some problems